# How to open automatically the Swagger page of a Spring Boot app when running from Intellij?

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, swagger-ui

In my Spring Boot application, I have a Swagger page.

I would like that after I launch the application from IntelliJ, it will also automatically run the browser and open the Swagger page.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are hosting your swagger file using something like [springdoc](https://springdoc.org/), or you have a static html swagger, you can add a before launch task to your project configuration.

Go to the current project configuration:

[image]

[image]

Got to modify options
[image]

Check Add before launch task

[image]

Then Add a task to run browser, where you can add a html file or an url.